# Calling a string[] from another class is appearing null

Tags: java, arrays, class

I'm sort of new to programming so I'm sure this is an easy answer.

Basically, in my main method I want to do this:

...

`wordtime = new LabelField("" + DataStored.words[0]);`

...

Now in the DataStored class I have:
...

```
public static String[] words;
{
    words = new String[2];

    words[0] = "Oil sucks!";
    words[1] = "Do you know that I can talk?";
}
```

...

So everytime I try to compile the program, it is getting stopped at the main class by saying that  DataStored.words[0] is null. How can I get it to populate the fields from the other class? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're initializing `words` in a *non-static* initialization block in `DataStored`. This means that `words` won't be initialized until you actually *construct* an instance of `DataStored`, which is probably not what you want.

You need to make the initialization block *static*, like this:

```
public static String[] words;
static { // <---------------------
    words = new String[2];

    words[0] = "Oil sucks!";
    words[1] = "Do you know that I can talk?";
}
```

This will cause the block to be run when the `DataStored` class is *loaded*.

Answer (score 6):

You've written an *initializer block* there - it will be executed every time you create a new instance of `DataStored`, but not *until* that time. I suspect you want:

```
public static String[] words = { "Oil sucks!", "Do you know that I can talk?" };
```

It's also a bad idea to have public fields like this, at least for anything other than constants (which would include immutable types in my view).

(I doubt that this is failing at *compile* time though - it's an *execution-time* failure. It's worth being clear about the difference.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to initialize `words` properly you need to do it in a *static block*, which is run as soon as the class is loaded. An *initializer block*, which you have used, is only run when an instance of the class is created, just before the constructor is called. So when you call `DataStored.words[0]`, the initializer hans't been run, and `words` is still null.

```
public static String[] words;

static
{
    words = new String[2];

    words[0] = "Oil sucks!";
    words[1] = "Do you know that I can talk?";
}
```

Or you can simply do:

```
 public static String[] words = new String[]{"Oil sucks!","Do you know that I can talk?"};
```

Or shorter still:

```
 public static String[] words = {"Oil sucks!","Do you know that I can talk?"};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you define the static block initializing these two variable in Class DataStored. You can access it.

Class DataStored {

public static String[] words;

Static {

```
words[0] = "Oil sucks!";
words[1] = "Do you know that I can talk?";
```

}

}

Answer (score -1):

> public static String[] words; {
>       words = new String[2];
>
> ```
> words[0] = "Oil sucks!";
> words[1] = "Do you know that I can talk?"; }
> ```

If you want to use this as a method for initializing the `words` instead of declaring an array of String's then add parathesis after words in the method header and remove the semi-colon.

Comment: -1. Your code is exactly equivalent to the code in the question, just with some whitespace changes.

Comment: I was only quoting his code.  Not changing it.  I stated the change he needed in my comment.

Comment: `public static String[] words() { words = new String[2];

words[0] = "Oil sucks!";
words[1] = "Do you know that I can talk?"; }`

Comment: What you've accomplished there is to let someone call `words()` to initialize the `words` static field. Why do that, when the field can be statically initialized automatically?